# Which is faster than react js and regular html ajax for json parse?

Tags: json, ajax, node.js, reactjs, axios

I studied react js.

**I would like to know the benefits of React js for json parse. !!!!**

I know that react is very fast because virtual dom and data flow.

What I was wondering is JSON parse.

In general html, we use ajax to do a json parse.
for example......  like this:

```
$.ajax({

  dataType: "json",

  url: url,

  data: data,

  success: success

});
```

In the case of React, ....

There are many ways, but if you use axios-redux-node-react js.
like this ....

// Performing a GET request

```
axios.get('https://api.github.com/users/' + username)

  .then(function(response){

    console.log(response.data); // ex.: { user: 'Your User'}

    console.log(response.status); // ex.: 200

  });
```

so, finally

**1. Which is faster than react js and regular html ajax for json parse from url (dynamic asynch..... )???**

**2. What is the fastest way to do json parse with react js?**

I need example ...... please ... please!!!

Comment: both `$ajax` and `axios` are wrappers around XHR.  Most likely they both use `JSON.parse` if the content-type is application/json.

Comment: I want to compare react and html......

Comment: `$ajax` is not html, it is javascript (jquery).  `axios` is not react, it is an XHR wrapper (again in javascript).

Comment: And.......    2. What is the fastest way to do json parse with react js?